# Passing Props to Reflux store?

Tags: reactjs, refluxjs

Is it possible/advisable to pass props to a Refluxjs store?  I'm refactoring some existing code that takes an API path as one of it's parameters.

My JSX looks like this:

```
<Panel panelTitle="Administrators" >
    <UserTable path='/api/admins'/>
</Panel>
<Panel panelTitle="Managers" >
    <UserTable path='/api/managers'/>
</Panel>
```

Path is used to load the data from my server. Since both API path's return the same type of data only the request path is different.

When refactoring this to Refluxjs stores, I'd expect to pass this in as a prop or variable to the store.

Am I missing something in the documentation or approaching this incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you would pass it as an action parameter.